# Jabba's Palace: Lego Star Wars the Complete Saga

Tags: lego-star-wars

How to enter Jabba's palace in Chapter 1 of Episode 6 in Lego Star Wars the Complete Saga?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assemble all the pieces near the door.  After you destroy the guns that appear hop up on the platform to make the third appear.  When you destroy that, the door will open.

Comment: you don't need to complete Episode V though.

Comment: @hyperviper11 Updated.